# Constructing Wolfram Alpha Query for Solar Position

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, astronomy

When I use Mathematica calls to WolframAlpha, it clearly knows about the motion of the sun, so I can request the solar declination at any date/time:

[image]

[image]

But I'm having great difficulty crafting a query that goes the other way.  "What date and time does the solar declination exactly equal -18 degrees?"

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The solar declination for a given date `d` can be found with

```
SunPosition[d, CelestialSystem -> "Equatorial"]
```

as stated [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SunPosition.html#17903267).

We can use `FindRoot` to invert this like so:

```
t0 = AbsoluteTime[Now];

declination[t_?NumericQ] := QuantityMagnitude[
  SunPosition[DateObject[t0 + t], CelestialSystem -> "Equatorial"][[-1]], 
  "AngularDegrees"
]

toffset = t /. FindRoot[declination[t] == -18, {t, 0}, Method -> "Secant"]
```

> ```
> 748714.5223444804`
> ```

```
date = DateObject[t0 + toffset]
```

[image]

```
SunPosition[date, CelestialSystem -> "Equatorial"]
```

[image]